# Invalid YAML in Netplan/Bridging/VLAN tags for qemu/libvertd

Tags: networking, 18.04, kvm-virtualization, qemu, netplan

I am new to netplan and Ubuntu 18.04 , and am trying to set up a VM host using `qemu/libvert`. The issue is with creating a netplan yaml file that meets our needs and works

- Interface eno1 is a management interface. It works fine in the configuration below.
- Interface eno2 will be a dedicated trunk to provide connectivity to the VMs with the rest of the network with a .1Q trunk.
- The interface the VMs will access is a trunk with 4 seperate .1Q tagged vlans.
- Each VM needs direct access to the network using a local IP address (to the VM) assigned to the appropriate bridge/vlan.
- No NAT on the network interfaces of the host.
- As a network engineer, I still belive a "bridge" is Layer 2. No need for an IP address (which also implies traffic will be NAT'ed on the interface)

The bridging/vlan examples at https://netplan.io/examples give me an error message:

```
Invalid YAML at //etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml line 24 column 5: did not find expected key
```

System details:

- OS: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
- netplan: netplan/bionic 1.10.1-5build1 amd64
- qemu/kvm: qemu-kvm/bionic-updates,now 1:2.11+dfsg-1ubuntu7.4 amd64
  [installed] qemu-kvm/bionic-security 1:2.11+dfsg-1ubuntu7.3 amd64
  qemu-kvm/bionic 1:2.11+dfsg-1ubuntu7 amd64

Any help would be appreciated.

`/etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml` contents:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eno1:
      addresses:
        - 192.168.xxx.7/24
      gateway4: 192.168.xxx.1
      nameservers:
        addresses:
          - 192.168.xxx.3
          - 9.9.9.9
    eno2: {}

  bridges:
    br20:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      interfaces: [ vlan20 ] <<=This is line 24 in the error message
     br50:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      interfaces: [ vlan50 ]
     br90:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      interfaces: [ vlan90 ]
     br100:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      interfaces: [ vlan100 ]

  vlans:
    vlan1:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      accept-ra: no
      id: 1
      link: eno2
    vlan20:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      accept-ra: no
      id: 20
      link: eno2
    vlan50:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      accept-ra: no
      id: 50
      link: eno2
    vlan90:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      accept-ra: no
      id: 90
      link: eno2
    vlan100:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      accept-ra: no
      id: 100
      link: eno2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`br50`, `br90` and `br100` are all indented one space too many.  They need to line up with `br20` like:

```
  bridges:
    br20:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      interfaces: [ vlan20 ]
    br50:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      interfaces: [ vlan50 ]
    br90:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      interfaces: [ vlan90 ]
    br100:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      interfaces: [ vlan100 ]
```

Comment: Thanks Stephen! That worked. I thought I had already worked through the yaml indentation issues (stupid yaml...). Removed the spaces and it worked. I appreciate your quick reply.

Comment: As for YAML, it it is actually a very nice ML.  Suggest using an editor that is YAML aware.  It can show these issues immediately.

Comment: Of course. Where were my manners... Thanks again!